# How can I update the multiple records using PUT in Web Api in one Call?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I update the multiple records using PUT in Web Api in one Call?
For updating single record the URL would be 
`http://localhost:4211/api/AuditChecklist/{id}`, 
but what should I pass in place of `{id}` for updating multiple records in one call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API would need to support this, and it doesn't look like it does. Your best bet might be to employ a for loop in the client code calling the API. Or you could write your API to accept a JSON body with a variable length hashtable containing the values to update and their new value.